# Python: How to use output of "listfiles" to delete/ move/ etc. files

Tags: python, list, directory, delete-file, os.walk

**Background:**

My target is to find dublicate files in two differen folders (without subfolders). To do that, I use the following Python script:

```
###Check ob alle Archive noch vorhanden oder ob Daten bei Check gelöscht wurden
def listfiles(path):
    files = []
    for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(path):
        dir = dirName.replace(path, '')
        for fname in fileList:
                if fname.endswith("_GIS.7z"):
                    files.append(os.path.join(dir, fname))
    return files

x = listfiles(root)
y = listfiles(backupfolderGIS)

#q = [filename for filename in x if filename not in y]

files_only_in_x = set(x) - set(y) 
files_only_in_y = set(y) - set(x)
files_only_in_either = set(x) ^ set(y)
files_in_both = set(x) & set(y)
all_files = set(x) | set(y)

print "Alle Datein:"
print all_files
print " "

print "Nur im Zwischenspeicher:"
print files_only_in_x
print " "

print "Nur im Backupordner:"
print files_only_in_y
print " "

print "Nur einem von beiden Ordnern:"
print files_only_in_either
print " "

print "In beiden Ordnern:"
print files_in_both
print " "
```

The relevant output variable/ list is `files_in_both` (folders); it shows me the dublicates; if I use `print`, it looks like `set(['NameoftheProject_GIS.7z', 'NameofanotherProject_GIS.7z'])`.

**Question:**

How can I use this output/ information (of dublicate files in directories) to delete/ move them? Here for example the files `NameoftheProject_GIS.7z` and `NameofanotherProject_GIS.7z` in folder `backupfolderGIS` / list `files_in_both`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`os.walk` recursively checks all folders and subfolders starting from the root dir you pass, you want to check *two different folders (without subfolders)*  so just search each folder with *glob*, if you want to move you can use [shutil.move](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.move):

```
from glob import iglob
from os import path
from shutil import move

pt1, pt2 = "/path_1", "path_2"
dupe = set(map(path.basename, iglob("/path_1./*_GIS.7z"))).intersection(map(path.basename, iglob("/path_2./*_GIS.7z")))

for fle in dupe:
    # move(src, dest)
    move(path.join(pt1, fle), "wherever")
```

Or to delete use [os.remove](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.remove):

```
for fle in dupe:
    os.remove(path.join(pt1, fle))
```

If you want to move/delete the file from pt2 then pass that to `path.join` in place of pt1.

You could also use *str.endwith* with `os.listdir`:

```
dupe = set(fname for fname in os.listdir(pt1) if fname.endswith("_GIS.7z")).intersection(fname for fname in os.listdir(pt2) if fname.endswith("_GIS.7z"))
```

To avoid repeating you can put it in a function:

```
from shutil import move
from os import path, listdir
def listfiles(path, end):
    return set(fname for fname in listdir(path) if fname.endswith(end))

for fle in listfiles(pt1,"_GIS.7z").intersection(listfiles(pt2, "_GIS.7z")):
    move(path.join(t1, fle), "wherever")
```

Now if you did want to check all folders for files with the same basename and so something for dupe name, you would need to keep a record of the full paths, you can group all common files by basename using a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from os import path, walk
from collections import defaultdict

def listfiles(pth, end):
    files = defaultdict(list)
    for dirName, subdirList, fileList in walk(pth):
        for fname in fileList:
            if fname.endswith(end):
                files[fname].append(path.join(dirName, fname))
    return files
```

You will get a dict where the keys are the basenames and the values are lists of files with the full path to each, any list with more than one vaulue means you have at least two files with the same name but you should remember have the same basename does not mean the files are actually the same.

Comment: Ah the no comment dv for a correct answer, well down downvoter ;)

Comment: Thanks, for solving my problem (very quick). It would be nice to solve it with my way of checking the folders, but your way is working well and fast! Don´t know why someone votes you down, will rate it up; will wait for 24 h and more answers before accepting it as the best answer.

Comment: @André, if you only have two folders then you should use either glob or os.listdir, walk is for recursively checking. If you did want to find files anywhere that had the same basename you could use the os.walk approach, one way to do that would be to use a dict, I will add an example in a minute

Comment: Thanks for your time! Works as needed. I accept it as the answer. Greetings from Germany to Ireland

Comment: I've taken knowledge abuout "the files are not actually the same", but because this part of the script belongs to a backup script, where the files will not be the same - with the exception of the name - it works for me.